# ClassNotFoundException: AutoImportMethodFactory SoapUI 5.2.1 open source

Tags: jenkins, soapui, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Jenkins 2.32.2 and SoapUI Open Source 5.2.1 version.
Below excpetion is thrown while executing below command from Jenkins pre build.

Command Configured :

```
"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat" -s"User ManagementTestSuite" -c"List All User TestCase" -r -f"D:\******\SoapUI\Report" "D:\********\SoapUI\REST-Project---User-Management-soapui-project.xml"
```

Error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

As per SoapUI open source feature list, Jenkins integration does not require Pro version. And as per above `ClassNotFoundException`, it looks like Pro version is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SoapUI 5.2.1 onwards, that is expected. You may also find the same in [SoapUI Community](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory-ClassNotFoundException-when-executing/td-p/105397)

If you want to avoid those errors, remove /move files from the following directory:

Note that you need to replace your user below.

```
C:\Users\<user name>\.soapuios\plugins\
```

or

```
C:\Users\<user name>\.soapui\plugins
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I have checked files under C:\Users\<user name>\.soapuios\plugins\ folder. This folder contains zero files. So kindly suggest which files needs to remove...

Comment: Have you replaced your user name in that? Any thing under `C:\Users\<user name>\.soapui\plugins`

Comment: No need to replace user as .soapui folder is already created under my login user name. for example : C:\Users\ashish\.soapui\plugins.. let me know if we need to give jenkins login user name instead of windows user login name

Comment: I mean with your user name on the system. You may not have a directory with `user name` under `C:\Users` You did not tell what happened to alternative one? or if you are looking into the right directory?

Comment: Yes system login user name is already created when i have installed SoapUI Open Source 64 bit software with plugin folder..

Comment: Not sure if you are following the instruction  correctly. I know system user will be there. But are you looking into the right location to see if there any jar files? If so, move them out from there. And restart soapui.

Comment: Let me install soapUI open Source 5.3.1 latest again and try to execute SoapUI test suites again.... Will follow same instruction and update you.

Comment: There is only _5.3_ available. You would get the same error there too and remove /move those from the mentioned directory.

Comment: Fyip. I am checking jar files which needs to remove .... C:\Users\121232\.soapuios\plugins .... 121232 is my userid.. no such file exist under pluings folder... meanwhile i am installing SoapUI latest versiob again and will follow same instruction suggested by you and update you the result.

Comment: Finally Issue is resolved, Uninstalled SoapUI from C:/ and Installed latest version of SoapUI 5.3 in D:/Software and no need to remove any jar from plugin folder. It is working perfectly fine.